# Where is Alfred Tarski buried?

Tags: mathematicians, 20th-century, death, logicians

Where is [Alfred Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tarski) buried?

He was a famous Polish mathematician. He died in 1983 in Berkeley, California, USA, according to Wikipedia. I tried a search on [Find a Grave](https://www.findagrave.com), but there is no entry for his name. I also tried a multilingual search. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that such information is **not** available on the Fefermans' [biography](https://books.google.com/books?id=wqktlxHo9wkC&lpg=PP1).

Comment: If his son Jan is still alive, you might be able to ask him.

Answer (score 8):

Not buried, cremated. The urn with his ashes is in a columbarium in Oakland, if I remember correctly - I visited the place in 1990s with his son Jan.

Comment: Urszula Wybraniec-Skardowska, "Alfred Tarski - the man who defined truth",
*Prace Naukowe Akademii im. Jana Długosza w Częstochowie. Filozofia*, nr 5,
pp. 67-78, 2008: " *There is another resting spot: an urn containing his ashes (along with ashes of his wife Maria) which is shaped like a book. The book is placed in a unique memorial: The Chapel of the Chimes, not far away from Berkeley, in Oakland. [...] The wing in which the book-urn with Alfred Tarski’s ashes is stored is inscribed in its upper part with the words: HOW SWEET THEIR MEMORY STILL.* "

Comment: For Chapel of the Chimes, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapel_of_the_Chimes_(Oakland,_California)).